# Spring Security whitelisting approach using annotations and a global denyAll

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations, whitelist

At the moment I try to figure out how Spring Security evaluates the given URL, expression and annotations. So far it seems like it always checks the entries from `security-context.xml` first. And if that's a `denyAll` it will simply stop further processing of the request.

Maybe I forgot to set some configuration option, but (in my eyes) it's not possible to build a nice whitelist using Spring Security's annotations (like `@Secured`, `@PermitAll`, etc.).

What I want is basically to annotate the methods inside a `@Controller` for **allowing** access. For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public MyController {
    @RequestMapping("")
    public void tryToGetSomething() {
      // no security annotation -> denyAll
    }

    @RequestMapping("/public")
    @PermitAll
    public void tryToGetSomethingPublic() {
      // this will always have access allowed
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    public void tryToGetSomethingReallyImportant() {
      // this can only be accessed by admins
    }
}
```

The main reason for this approach is: Security `;-)`. It's always possible to forget some annotations while writing code. And with this method such a mistake won't affect security of sensitive data.

So my question is: How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use security pointcuts in conjuction with annotations:

```xml
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <!-- Disable access to all controller methods -->
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.mycompany.controllers.*Controller.*(..))"
         access="ROLE_THAT_DOES_NOT_EXIST"/>
</global-method-security>
```

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public MyController {

    @RequestMapping("")
    public void tryToGetSomething() {
      // pointcut rule -> no one has ROLE_THAT_DOES_NOT_EXIST -> no one can call this code
    }

    @RequestMapping("/public")
    @PreAuthorized("permitAll")
    public void tryToGetSomethingPublic() {
      // annotations take precedence over pointcuts, so anyone can call this code due to @PreAuthorized("permitAll") rule
    }
}
```

See [corresponding entry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-protect-pointcut) from the official documentation. Maybe you can use `denyAll` instead of `ROLE_THAT_DOES_NOT_EXIST`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll check that. But first I've got to find out, how to use pointcuts in Spring Security javaconfig. I'll report back later.

Comment: every get this going?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve the same, but the problem is that method security level applies to every method called through AOP. If you deny access by default, you will will have to annotate pretty much everything :)

With URL based security, you can proceed by whitelist:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anyRequest().denyAll();
}
```

The obvious drawback, unfortunately, is that every URL has to be authorized here, creating a kind of dependency magnet. But maybe it is a good thing to centralize URL path mapping ?